# CheckBox in ChildView of ExpandableListView

Tags: android, checkbox, expandablelistview

In my Android application, I have an ExpandableListView with each group having only one child, which contains a checkbox. I'm having trouble in setting the value of the checkboxes.

I'm retrieving the values of checkbox from database and storing it in an integer ArrayList with values 0 & 1 for checked and unchecked respectively

```
ArrayList<Integer> trustedList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Initially, I've put all the entries in database as 1.

The Adapter class for ExpandableListView is as follows :

```
class DataAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Context context;
    LayoutInflater lat = getLayoutInflater();

    CheckBox cb;

    public DataAdapter(Context context) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.context = context;
    }

@Override
    public View getChildView(int group, int child, boolean arg2, View v,
            ViewGroup arg4) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        v = lat.inflate(R.layout.inflate_list, null);
        cb = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);

        if (trustedList.get(group) == 1)
            cb.setChecked(true);
        else
            cb.setChecked(false);

    return v;
 }
}
```

But I'm getting unchecked values for the checkboxes. Also, on checking the checkbox and collapsing and expanding the group, I'm getting unchecked checkbox again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class DataAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Context context;
    LayoutInflater lat = getLayoutInflater();

    CheckBox cb;

    public DataAdapter(Context context) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.context = context;
    }

@Override
    public View getChildView(int group, int child, boolean arg2, View v,
            ViewGroup arg4) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        v = lat.inflate(R.layout.inflate_list, null);
        cb = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);

        if (trustedList.get(group) == 1)
            cb.setChecked(true);
        else
            cb.setChecked(false);
cb.setOnCheckChangeListener(new CheckchangeListener(group) );

    return v;
 }
class CheckchangeListener implements OnCheckedChangeListener {
        private int position;

        public CheckchangeListener(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

            this.position= position;

        }

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                boolean isChecked) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (isChecked) {
                //updateyour list and database here

            } else {
                //updateyour list and database here

            }

        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Thanks Rohit... And btw, I also found an other solution for the problem but yours is short n sweet... Thanks

Comment: Hi when I use this code for a Checkbox - there is just CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener but I have a Checkbox -